# Laptop shuts off below 60%

Tags: power-management, shutdown, battery

Since last few days I have been facing this problem. Laptop suddenly shuts off when reaches 60% on Battery. Same thing is happening in Windows 10 as well as Ubuntu 16.04LTS.
I have a Lenovo g580. And I dont have any special power management / drivers installed in either Ubuntu or Windows.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your battery is about to die.

Comment: To finish @Benny's thought, you need to get a new battery.